# How to delete datafile when no longer has tablespace in Oracle 11gR2 express?

Tags: oracle

I have

```
SQL> select name from v$datafile;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\SYSTEM.DBF
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\SYSAUX.DBF
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\UNDOTBS1.DBF
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\USERS.DBF
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\SERVER\DATABASE\DONHUVY_TABLESPACE.DAT
```

and

```
SQL> select tablespace_name from user_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS
DONHUVY_TABLESPACE
DONHUVY_TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE
DONHUVY2_TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE

8 rows selected.
```

I want delete all things has `donhuvy2`

update:

```
SELECT FILE_NAME, BLOCKS, TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_DATA_FILES UNION ALL SELECT FILE_NAME, BLOCKS, TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_TEMP_FILES

SQL> SELECT FILE_NAME, BLOCKS, TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_DATA_FILES UNION ALL SELECT FILE_NAME, BLOCKS, TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_TEMP_FILES;

FILE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BLOCKS TABLESPACE_NAME
---------- ------------------------------
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\USERS.DBF
     12800 USERS

C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\SYSAUX.DBF
     84480 SYSAUX

C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\UNDOTBS1.DBF
     48640 UNDOTBS1


FILE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BLOCKS TABLESPACE_NAME
---------- ------------------------------
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\SYSTEM.DBF
     46080 SYSTEM

C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\SERVER\DATABASE\DONHUVY_TABLESPACE.DAT
      1280 DONHUVY_TABLESPACE

C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\TEMP.DBF
      2560 TEMP


FILE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BLOCKS TABLESPACE_NAME
---------- ------------------------------
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\SERVER\DATABASE\DONHUVY_TEMPORARY_TABLE_SP
ACE
       640 DONHUVY_TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE


7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
DROP TABLESPACE DONHUVY2_TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9004.htm).

Comment: If you have DBA , post the output of: `SELECT FILE_NAME, BLOCKS, TABLESPACE_NAME
  FROM DBA_DATA_FILES
UNION ALL
SELECT FILE_NAME, BLOCKS, TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_TEMP_FILES`

Comment: I don't see any `donhuvy2`in your results

Comment: step1: `CREATE TABLESPACE donhuvy2_tablespace DATAFILE 'donhuvy2_tablespace.dat' SIZE 10M AUTOEXTEND ON;` step2: I want delete: **donhuvy2_tablespace.dat** I have been run your query success, but what I want is delele file **.dat**